# Validate string for url without protocol or www if top level domain exists

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, validation

I am trying to validate user input strings for valid URL. I am able to test for strings that either have an http(s):// or www. Here is my code:

```
var urlRegEx = /((([A-Za-z]{3,9}:(?:\/\/)?)(?:[\-;:&=\+\$,\w]+@)?[A-Za-z0-9\.\-]+|(?:www\.|[\-;:&=\+\$,\w]+@)[A-Za-z0-9\.\-]+)((?:\/[\+~%\/\.\w\-]*)?\??(?:[\-\+=&;%@\.\w]*)#?(?:[\.\!\/\\\w]*))?)/g;
if(urlRegEx.test(str)){
  alert('Valid URL');
}else{
    alert('Invalid URL');
}
```

It works fine, even for cases like https://google.co.in/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=list%20of%20all%20top%20level%20domains

However, it does not validate abc.com or domain-name.tld

I would want it to work something like Whatsapp, where any string followed by a ".", followed by a top level domain, gets converted to a url but other strings don't. For example, abc.com, abc.net, abc.au etc., all get converted to URLs. However, abc.anything, won't get converted to URL.
Even this: abc.au?kgfjhg#kjhkjh=jkhkjh/kjdhkjd is identified as a URL at Whatsapp.

Answer (score 0):

Sure, here is an example javascript regex:

```
^[a-zA-Z]{3,9}\.(com|au|org)[^a-zA-Z]
```

What it does: It matches something that starts with 3 to 9 alphabet characters, then a dot ("."), and then one of several known top level domains (com|au|org) which is a list that you can expand, followed by, if anything, a non-alphabet character (so that com and com/x will be valid top level domains, but comx will not be valid).

Note this is not a regex to match standard URLs.

Btw I used [this site](http://myregexp.com/) to write and test the regex live, maybe you'll find it useful.

If you'd like more features for the regex, feel free to comment and I'll add them

Enjoy!